# Connect to ASP.NET Development Server from handheld emulator

Tags: windows-mobile, web-services, asp.net-development-serv

I have a Windows mobile project and a Web Service. I can connect to the dev server with a console app, but not the windows mobile emulator.

The emulator can access the network without issue. I have IIS installed. If I deploy the Web Service to the local IIS and update the reference the emulator can connect without issue.

Firefox can connect to the dev server at localhost but not the box's IP ...the firewall is completely off.

So the question in other words is how can I convince the dev server to accept connections from the outside (outside as in not on my dev box)?

Comment: u mean, u r not able to connect to the dev server from emulator?.
but u can connect through Firefox on desktop right..
so u want to get connect to the server through emulator.. this s wat u ment right

Comment: u got it :)  I would like to connect the emulator to the dev server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing how no one has been able to answer this in 3 years... let's just go ahead and say it.

You can't.